# Q: Updating a ProgressBar with real results (includes code)

Tags: java, android, splash-screen, runnable, android-progressbar

I am designing a functional Splashscreen that loads my App, with a `ProgressBar` on it.

As per the official Android Developers Documentation, I am using a `Thread`+`Runnable` to do my loading work, and set up the `ProgressBar`.

Everything inside my Code below has come directly from the Android Documentation.

My Questions are after my Code below..

Here is my current Code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

private ProgressBar mProgress;

private int mProgressStatus = 0;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (mProgressStatus < 100) {

                mProgressStatus = doWork();

                // Update the progress bar 
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
// Set up a method here to do my loading work called doWork?
}
```

**My Questions are:**

- I see that the Code is setting the `mProgressStatus` to be equal to `doWork()`. I would assume I need to create a Method called `doWork()` and put all of my Code inside of it related to loading the App, and the ProgressBar will be updated accordingly.. However, `mProgressStatus` is an `int`, so how am I supposed to implement `doWork()` as intended?
- Also, I noticed that in the declarations of the Code, `private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;` is never used - so am I supposed to insert this somewhere?
- Lastly, in the example, the `onCreate` uses `Bundle icicle` instead of `savedInstanceState`.. Is this correct for my Splash activity to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `AsyncTask` for this purpose,Please refer below code

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressBar mProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    new DoWork().execute(this);
}
   protected class DoWork extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {
             //do some task say 20% of complete task
              publishProgress(20);
            //do some task say 50% of complete task
        publishProgress(50);
        //do some task say 100% of complete task
        publishProgress(100);
            return null;
        }

        //Called just before execution begins
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute()");
        mProgress.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        //called from the publish progress
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values); 
        mProgress.setProgress(values[0]);           
        }

    // when execution is completed
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mProgress.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In your way it is straight forward, doWork() is technically not a method.
Its the background task your executing inline as in

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (mProgressStatus < 100) { // Show progress till its 100
                //for example your downloading something, everytime you hit the while loop ,you'll update the mProgressStatus to current progress.
                //I need to download file of size 10mb
                //every time while loops execute , you calcluate size downloaded say 1mb i.e.. 1mb of 10mb means 10% progressed so set mProgressStatus to 10
                int percentageOfFileDownloaded = (downloadedfileSize/TotalFileSize) * 100; //Just for example
                mProgressStatus = percentageOfFileDownloaded;
                  //At one moment your entire file will be downloaded (10mb of 10mb) so update mProgressStatus to 100; it will break while loop.
                // Update the progress bar 
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
}
```

Comment: The example I am using in my code above is directly from Google.. and it seems far more simple as well.. In any case, do you know how I can make the example i posted work? or the answers to the questions I had?

Comment: So since I have a big block of code to execute, how can I determine how much of it has been completed? and where would I put it? Because my case isn't as simple as 'how much of a download is done', its more complicated than that.. ..?

Comment: Thank you for your example, however my needs are much more complex -- I have an entire Code Block that needs to be translated into a ProgressBar.. So while I totally understand how your example would work for something as simple as downloading a file, I DON'T understand how I can determine percentage completed based on an entire Block of Code.. So could I possible get an example of how I can implement the sample Code I posted to accomplish determining the Progress of an entire Block of Code?